# displaying days of the week in java script

Tags: javascript

I need to - Create a HTML form with a text entry field and a button.. When a number  is     entered in the text entry field and  the button clicked a  Javascript function  called DayOfTheWeek() is invoked. This function uses   a switch statement to determine the day of the week corresponding to the number entered, i.e if the  number entered  is 1  the message “It’s Monday” is  displayed, if the   number entered is 2  the message “It’s Tuesday”  is displayed  and so on. If a  number which is not between 1-7 is entered then the message “Not a valid day of the week” is  displayed.

my html

```
<input type="text" name="text1"/>

<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="days(text1.value);"/>
```

my java script

```
function days(dayOfTheWeek)
{
switch (dayOfTheWeek) {

case “1”: 
    alert(“It\’s Monday”);
        break;
case “2”:
        alert(“It\’s Tuesday”);
    break;

case “3”:
        alert(“It\’s Wednesday”);
    break;

case “4”:
        alert(“It\’s Thursday”);
    break;

case “5”:
        alert(“It\’s Friday”);
    break;

case “6”:
        alert(“It\’s Saturday”);
    break;

case “7”:
        alert(“It\’s Sunday”);
    break;

default:
        alert(“Not a valid day”);
    break;  

}
}
```

PLEASE HELP I keep getting an error with firebug saying days is not defind

Comment: *Where* did you define days? Include an external script?

Comment: You've got a huge syntax error: Use `"` quotes instead of `“”`

Answer (score 2):

```
function days(dayOfTheWeek) {
  var weekday=new Array(7);
  weekday[0]="Sunday";
  weekday[1]="Monday";
  weekday[2]="Tuesday";
  weekday[3]="Wednesday";
  weekday[4]="Thursday";
  weekday[5]="Friday";
  weekday[6]="Saturday";

  var n = weekday[dayOfTheWeek];
  return n;
}
```

Comment: In his code the dayOfTheWeek is 1-7 not 0-6 so you need to add -1 or so on dayOfTheWeek to get the correct index.

Comment: Also, "Sunday" is considered the last day in his question, not the first . . . but, yeah, this approach was my first thought as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code

```
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" />
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="javascript:days(parseInt(document.getElementById('text1').value));" />
<script language=javascript>
function days(dayOfTheWeek)
{
switch (dayOfTheWeek) {

case 1: 
    alert("It\’s Monday");
        break;
case 2:
        alert("It\’s Tuesday");
    break;

case 3:
        alert("It\’s Wednesday");
    break;

case 4:
        alert("It\’s Thursday");
    break;

case 5:
        alert("It\’s Friday");
    break;

case 6:
        alert("It\’s Saturday");
    break;

case 7:
        alert("It\’s Sunday");
    break;

default:
        alert("Not a valid day");
    break;  

}
}
</script>
```