# Javascript Displaying WeekDays from userinput

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript function, as when user input 1 in textbox and click on the button, it will prompt "Monday". So how can I do this. Here is the list:

```
`1=Monday
2=Tuesday
3=Wednesday
4=Thursday
5=Friday
6=Saturday`
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer for this question:

[displaying days of the week in java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989095/displaying-days-of-the-week-in-java-script/22989251#22989251)

I think this will help.

happyCoding :D

Answer (score 0):

Make a array with those values, like  ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];`. 
Do note that Sunday is missing...

Then add a event listener to your input to detect `keyup`for example, and use the array index from the input value.

You can/should make this a little bit more advanced to not give errors if users insert letters instead of numbers or numbers bigger than the days you have.

Example:

```
var days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var value = parseInt(this.value) > 5 ? 0 : parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    alert(days[value]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function ShowDay(){
            var input = document.getElementById("txDay").value;
            if(!isNaN(input)){
                if(input > 0 && input < 8){
                    alert(DayOfWeek(input));
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("txDay").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("txDay").focus();
                }
            }    
        }

        function DayOfWeek(x){
            var days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'];
            return days[x-1];
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txDay" />
    <button type="button" onclick="ShowDay()">Try me</button>
</body>
```